# How to do such query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example of my documents.

```
  { username: 'John', score: 10 },
  { username: 'John', score: 9 },
  { username: 'John', score: 8 }, 
  { username: 'Alice', score: 9 }, 
  { username: 'Bob', score: 7 }
```

I want to select all the users whose `score` has **never** been 10.

Expected output:

```
  { username: 'Alice', score: 9 }, 
  { username: 'Bob', score: 7 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment in above answer, If your documents contains following documents :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55713e614e3a37ae89ef7b4b"), "username" : "John", "score" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55713e614e3a37ae89ef7b4c"), "username" : "John", "score" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55713e614e3a37ae89ef7b4d"), "username" : "John", "score" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55713e614e3a37ae89ef7b4e"), "username" : "Alice", "score" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55713e614e3a37ae89ef7b4f"), "username" : "Bob", "score" : 7 }
```

and you want to display those user whose score **never** been **10** means in above conditions `Alice and Bob` data you required. So check this below query :

```
db.collectionName.find({"username":{"$nin":db.collectionName.distinct("username",{"score":10})}})
```

this `db.collectionName.distinct("username",{"score":10})`distinct return array of those user whose `score:10` and use this array in find to check those username whose `nin` in `distinct` array.